# Puzzle: Win98, user has removed files, will not boot -- how to boot

Tags: boot, windows-98

A friend uses a Win98 for his small business. Unfortunately he deleted a few crucial files, one or two of them belonging to Windows. The main obstacles we have are that: (1) his disk contains commercial proprietary files that he uses in his business that can no longer be replaced, and (2) it's difficult to obtain a replacement IDE disk that could be used as a place to boot Windows from in his machine.

Can anyone suggest ways of making his machine bootable so that we can try to recover his files?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Run the Windows 98 setup disk and install it over itself. I seem to remember doing this as a "repair" install in the past. Basically you just need a Windows  install CD.

Answer (score 2):

To **recover files,** buy an IDE-to-SATA or even IDE-to-USB adapter. (They're plentiful on eBay and computer parts stores.) Use it to connect the disk to another computer.

I would suggest making a full image of the disk **before you do anything else,** so that you'll be able to restore in case it dies the next week. If the system is really as business-critical as you say, why would you be doing brain surgery on the only copy in existence? You never know whether a "repair" or "reinstall" operation is going to fix it, or just break it irreparably.

---

Once you've done that:

To **make the system bootable,** figure out which files were deleted, and copy them from a Win98 installation CD (using the [extract](http://www.uninets.net/~blaisdel/WindowsExtractCom.htm) DOS command). Make sure you have the correct Win98 release (first edition vs SE).

If too many files were deleted, run the Windows installer and point it at the same path. As @Mokubai says, it should detect the existing OS and repair it without losing any installed applications.